# is there a way that each commit in svn be a comment in jira with the same user made the commit

Tags: svn, jenkins, jira

I have a project and want to see each commit from svn as a comment in jira but with the same user that made the commit in svn.

currently we have the comments but with an user that we created for jenkins.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/tour . Your question not very clear..

Answer (score 0):

How do you make the svn commits end up in JIRA?

Typically you would use Fisheye on top of svn and enable the development tools integration between JIRA and Fisheye. This does show the commits with the correct committer.

More info is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/integrating-with-development-tools-776636216.html).

Comment: we are not using fisheye currently